# Mac Terminal Padding

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is it possible to add window padding to Terminal.app? Here's how it looks currently ...

[image: Mac Terminal.app with no border padding]
and here's how I would like it to look ...

[image: iTerm2 with border padding]
*iTerm2 with padding*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible with `Terminal.app`. This can be done with [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/), but you are obviously aware of that.

Comment: Great attention to the [tag:terminal] but don’t forget we want to use [tag:command-line] for the general case and reserve terminal for things that are specifically about the terminal app. See the tag descriptions or [meta] for more guidance. Thanks for being here!

Comment: @bmike Was this supposed to be a comment to the question? And this **is** specifically about the Terminal.app?

Comment: Hit us up in [chat] it was more a general comment to you and yes - the asker could also use the correct tags, but I saw you making some awesome edits and answers, so I went to the person doing the good work (as I saw it)

Comment: This question is one of the rare ones where terminal is a correct tag (and in addition to Command-line of course)